# Github: Add Signed-off by in commit without using -s param?

Tags: git, github

I would like this `Signed-off by` to be set automatically without me giving the -s parameter as I would normally do:

`git commit -s -m "message"`

I wish I could just give
`git commit -m" message"`

and `Signed-off by` to be put automatically at the end of the commit message.

Comment: `git config alias.scommit "commit -s"` and use `git scommit` from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, do this by creating an alias for `commit -s`.  You can also add it using a `commit-msg` hook if you want.  However, it's intentional that you cannot specify a configuration option for this.

The reason is that you are supposed to intentionally and deliberately sign-off your commit message in each instance, making the certification specified in the [Developer's Certificate of Origin](https://developercertificate.org/), and your sign-off could not be knowing and voluntary if it were added automatically.